# How do I optimize these C for loops?

Tags: c, performance, for-loop

I chose to do these [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems in C because I was under the impression that C is fast, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Both of the following loops are *extremely* slow:

```
int problem_7 () { 
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10001; i++) {
      for (int j = (i==1)?1:n+1; j > 0; j++) {
          int factorCounter = 0;
          for (int k = 1; k <= j/2; k++)
              factorCounter += (j % k == 0);
          if (factorCounter == 1) {
              n = j;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  return n;
}


long long int problem_10 () {
  long long int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
      int factorCount = 0;
      for (int j = 1; j <= i/2; j++) {
          factorCount += (i % j == 0);
          sum += i*(j == i/2 && factorCount == 1);
      }
  }

  return sum; 
}
```

Is there any way I can make these loops run faster? They do what they're supposed to do, but they each take like 5 minutes to execute.

Comment: Try doing the same in another language, see if the performance increases or decreases :-).

Comment: For Euler 7, I suggest you use the Sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes -- your code is a mess as is and I doubt anyone will bother to optimize your O(N^x) loops

Comment: Have you compiled the sources with optimization settings?

Comment: Your code is slow because of the sheer number of loops you are asking it to execute, not because C itself is slow.

Comment: Did you really mean to sum the result of a comparison?

Comment: @Alan It yields 1 for true and 0 for false, so he probably did.

Comment: @What are the correct answers?

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun While technically that works, it's pretty sloppy code.

Comment: @Alan I agree, I was just pointing out that he did in fact mean to do it :P

Comment: Btw - running your code for problem 7 took less than 10 seconds when I ran it - are you passing optimization flags to your compiler?  Or running in the dubbugger or some debug mode?  5 minutes is very long.

Comment: Btw, you've just learned that while C is fast, the most important thing is how good your code is and the complexity of the algorithm you are running. Well written code in any language will beat poorly written code in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With branch prediction using boolean numeric values is not as needed:

Looking at problem7 for example, this can be sped up by **using** if statements:

```
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10001; i++) {
      for (int j = (i==1)?1:n+1; j > 0; j++) {
          int factorCounter = 0;
          for (int k = 1; k <= j/2; k++)
          {
              if (j%k==0)                 // code is changed HERE
              {
                factorCounter ++;
                if (factorCounter > 1)
                {
                      break;
                }
              }                          // code change ends here
          }
          if (factorCounter == 1) {
              n = j;
              break;
          }
      }
```

This completes in **0.88secs** as opposed to the original's **9.5secs** -- over 10 times faster from that one change

**Explanation of optimization and rational for equivalence:**

The change made was from the original line:

```
factorCounter += (j % k == 0);
```

First change that to its equivalent:

```
if (j%k==0)
{
    factorCounter ++;
}
```

Notice how `factorCounter` can only increment, and after the loop any value over 1 is discarded because `(factorCounter == 1)` will be false, so once it is greater than 1, there is no reason to continue the loop.   Also notice that the value of `factorCounter` can only be changed when `(j%k==0)` so the test for `factorCounter > 1` should occur inside the if check, the code is now:

```
if (j%k==0)
{
      factorCounter ++;
      if (factorCounter > 1)
      {
         break;   // We stop the loop much earlier HERE
      }
}
```

And exiting the loop early is what gives the performance gain

Comment: Explain your changes from the original a step at a time.

Comment: @MohammadS. Good idea - this has been added

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll make this an answer. Your program is slow because your loops are poorly designed and poorly nested. I'm not going to do a complexity analysis, but you're somewhere in the range of O(N^x) where x > 4 (from what I can tell).

It's just bad programming and it has little to do with loop optimization. You need to use something like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to solve Euler 7. I won't give you the solution here, as with the Wiki article it's fairly trivial to solve.

Comment: "I won't give you the solution here.." No worries, someone else is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

C is fast.  Higher level languages can be fast as well.  But even the best compiler can't optimize out the extra operations you're having it do!  A simple way to reduce number of operations in your problem 7 algorithm would be to break the deepest for loop if factorCounter becomes greater than 1.  Sorry to break it to you but: it's not the compiler it's the algorithm!

Answer (score 1):

A more direct approach to the problem executes almost immediately. You don't really need that many optimizations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int j)
{
    for(int fac = 2; fac < sqrt(j)+0.5; ++fac)
        if(j%fac == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int primesFound = 1; // 2 is prime
    int possiblePrime = 1;

    while(primesFound != 10001)
    {
        possiblePrime += 2;
        if(isPrime(possiblePrime))
            ++primesFound;
    }

    cout << possiblePrime << endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice optimizations - i took a baby step approach :)

Comment: This is good code except giving the answer defeats the purpose of Project Euler...